# Trouble setting number attribute in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, attributes, nsnumber

I have an Entity "Item" in Core Data.  Item has two attributes: name and number.  name is an NSString* and number is an NSNumber*.  I specified "Integer 32" as the type for number in the Core Data modelling tool. The following code sets the name correctly but not the number:

```
Item *item = (Item *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item"
                       inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 

[item setName:@"test name"];
[item setNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:123]];
```

Logging card.name shows "test name" as expected.  Logging card.number shows a large random number.  I was expecting 123 since that's what I passed to numberWithInteger.

**Why isn't the number attribute being set correctly?**

A few notes:

- I created the Item class by selecting the "Item" Entity in the modeling tool and adding a new "Managed Object Class".  This created the properties etc for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a logging issue:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", item.number]);
```

needed to be

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.number]);
```

(Had to change %d to %@)